# Oracle XmlTable and XQuery: ignore case sensitivity

Tags: xml, oracle

In Oracle Database 11g 11.2.0.3.0 64bit Production, I would like to know if it is possible, in a query using XMLTABLE and XQuery to ignore case sensitivity; for example, suppose we have an xml files with tags:

```
/Warehouse
/Warehouse/WaterAccess
/Warehouse/RailAccess
```

We execute the following (example from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions253.htm#SQLRF06232):

```
SELECT warehouse_name warehouse,  
  warehouse2."Water", warehouse2."Rail"  
    FROM warehouses,  
    XMLTABLE('/Warehouse'  
    PASSING warehouses.warehouse_spec  
    COLUMNS   
    "Water" varchar2(6) PATH '/Warehouse/WaterAccess',  
    "Rail" varchar2(6) PATH '/Warehouse/RailAccess')   
    warehouse2;  


WAREHOUSE Water Rail
----------------------------------- ------ ------
Southlake, Texas Y N
San Francisco Y N
New Jersey N N
Seattle, Washington N Y
```

But, for some reasons, the next xml file contains the following tags (some letters lowercase):

```
/warehouse
/warehouse/WaterAccess
/warehouse/Railaccess
```

the same query will fail.
Is there any workaround (e.g. use a sort of UPPER)?
Thanks,
Igor

Comment: XML is **case-sensitive** by definition of World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) - contrary to HTML, for instance. So `/warehouse` is different to `/Warehouse`, you should correct your source data.

Comment: @Wernfried Thanks for the answer ; yes , you're right , but the source file is generated by a third-party application and so I would like to handle any future errors in the tags .

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT warehouse_name warehouse,  
  warehouse2."Water", warehouse2."Rail"  
    FROM warehouses,  
    XMLTABLE('/*/*'  
    PASSING warehouses.warehouse_spec  
    COLUMNS   
    "Water" varchar2(6) PATH '/WaterAccess',  
    "Rail" varchar2(6) PATH '/RailAccess')   
    warehouse2;
```